# initializer list constructor error with CRTP

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list, crtp

I'm wetting my feet with C++11 and am really confused why this doesn't work:

```
template <class T>
struct A {
  size_t size() const { return sizeof(T); }
};

struct B : A<B> {
  int x;
  int y;
};

B var {1, 5};
```

I'm using gcc 4.8.2 and get an error saying:

```
no matching function for call to 'B(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
```

It works just fine when I don't derive from `A`, so does the derivation somehow change the POD-ness of my struct `B`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Aggregate-initialization* requires your type to be an aggregate. An aggregate cannot have base classes:

> An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided
>   constructors (12.1), no private or protected non-static data members
>   (Clause 11), **no base classes** (Clause 10), and no virtual functions
>   (10.3).

Comment: Ah, so the second part of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special/7189821#7189821) doesn't apply. Thanks.

Comment: This [could change in C++17](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special/27511360#comment47403725_27511360) there is currently a proposal being considered.